# Network communication between C# server and JAVA client: how to handle that. transition?

Tags: java, networking, unsigned

I have a C# server that cannot be altered. In C#, a byte ranges fom 0 - 255, while in JAVA it ranges from -128 to 127.

I have read about the problem with unsigned byte/ints/etc and the only real option as I have found out is to use "more memory" to represent the unsigned thing:
http://darksleep.com/player/JavaAndUnsignedTypes.html

Is that really true?

So when having network communication between the JAVA client and the C# server, the JAVA client receives byte arrays from the server. The server sends them "as unsigned" but when received they will be interpreted as signed bytes, right?

Do I then have to typecast each byte into an Int and then add 127 to each of them?

I'm not sure here... but how do I interpret it back to the same values (int, strings etc) as I had on the C# server?

I find this whole situation extremely messy (not to mention the endianess-problems, but that's for another post).

Comment: If I don't recall my twos-complement math completely wrong, that would be -128 through +127 in Java (not -127 through +128), and as @JonSkeet points out, +0 through +255 (not +0 through +254) in C#.

Comment: Yeah yeah yeah. you get the idea...

Comment: I ended up using JAVA:s ByteBuffers and change order(...) on them, to translate from-and-to Little/Big-endian. If I didnt, it didnt work at all. When it comes to the signed-ness, I couldn't do anything else than to interpret a C# uint to a JAVA int, and just hope we dont go above about 2 billion...

Answer (score 2):

A byte is 0-255 in C#, not 0-254.

However, you really don't need to worry in most cases - basically in both C# and Java, a byte is 8 bits. If you send a byte array from C#, you'll receive the same bits in Java and vice versa. If you then convert parts of that byte array to 32-bit integers, strings etc, it'll all work fine. The signed-ness of bytes in Java is almost always irrelevant - it's only if you treat them *numerically* that it's a problem.

What's *more* of a problem is the potential for different endianness when (say) converting a 32-bit integer into 4 bytes in Java and then reading the data in C# or vice versa. You'd have to give more information about what you're trying to do in order for us to help you there. In particular do you already have a protocol that you need to adhere to? If so, that pretty much decides what you need to do - and how hard it will be depends on what the protocol is.

If you get to *choose* the protocol, you may wish to use a platform-independent serialization format such as [Protocol Buffers](http://protobuf.googlecode.com) which is available for both .NET and Java.

Comment: Thx. I see. Hmm, I shall try some more with the byte thing. However, when it comes to endianess I have also been looking on that quite a bit today. And yes, there is already a pre-defined protocol (that we wrote, but can't really change now). That protocol was written i C# and has a lot of unsigned numbers.

Comment: @Ted: It may be fiddly to write them out from Java, but it won't be *too* hard, I'm sure. However, you won't be able to represent unsigned values in Java *as* unsigned values - so if you have a `uint` in C#, you'll need to *either* store it in a `long` in Java *or* just account for the difference in how you use the values.

Comment: I am actually porting our C#/Windows Mobile application to Android, which is why Im looking into this now...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, yes ... the answer is to "use more memory", at least on some level.

You can *store* the data as a `byte` array in java, but when you need to use that data numerically you'll need to move up to an `int` and add 256 to negative values. A bitwise `&` will do this for you quickly and efficiently.

```
int foo;
if (byte[3] < 0)
    foo = (byte[3] & 0xFF);
else
    foo = byte[3];
```

Comment: I don't get that. How can I represent it as a long, if I am sending it to the C# server that represents it as an uint, 4 bytes? THe C#-server will get 8 bytes (long) and will take the first 4 bytes and cast it to an uint... which will be wrong Im guessing...

Comment: The whole byte array will be messed up, when the server expects 4 bytes to be interpreted as a uint... Very messay. Lets say I completely rewrite the whole protocol, do I have to stop using unsigned numbers on the C#-side altogether?

Comment: Well, no. You have the right number of *bits* on each end. The only issue is how they are interpreted. Yes, it's a pain, but you simply would need to send the signed equivalent from java so that the bit pattern was correct when cast to unsigned in C#. And when you're talking about multi-byte and worry about endian issues you'd want to convert to network byte ordering. If you were to redo the protocol you'd either want to move away from binary, or use an existing one that provides both Java and C# libraries so you didn't need to mess with it at all (google protocol buffers, for example).